# How to fix R CMD check NOTE on incoming feasibility due to 'Too Many Requests' for URLs

Tags: r, cran

Checking my R package on winbuilder (devel and release 4.0.3) yields a NOTE for incoming feasibility with many blocks like this:

```
Found the following (possibly) invalid URLs:
  URL: https://github.com/ropensci/drake
    From: inst/doc/third-party-integrations.html
          NEWS.md
    Status: 429
    Message: Too Many Requests
```

I used the package [{urlchecker}](https://github.com/r-lib/urlchecker) to make sure all URLs are correct (i.e. valid and no re-directs). Can I safely ignore this warning on submission? I assume I could probably reduce the number of URLs in my package to get rid of it but I'd want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: Please clarify if you are concerned about the NOTE on _local_ testing or on win-builder / CRAN / RHub / ...

Comment: I got Vienna to set up a GITHUB_PAT, but Dortmund hasn't so runs on Windoze still create the warnings for me. Some packages of mine have 100+ links as each PR and issue in NEWS is linked.  The NOTE is not an issue for rejection at CRAN so you are not _forced_ to remove the links---it is essentially up to you.  But package developers have no influence over the Windows run-time in Dortmind so <shrug_emoji_here>.

Comment: Oh, and *please* do not cross-post simulatenously to SO and Twitter.

Comment: Thanks. I tried clarifying the question (`devtools::check_win_devel()` -> winbuilder) and deleted the tweet.

Comment: `devtools` has nothing to do with it, it is just a dispatcher. You will find many emails from Uwe on the lists saying he does not touch `devtools` either.  It really is "just" his machine and setup aggregating too many pulls to github servers, so his boxen get the warning :-/   You could send him a quiet polite email suggesting the GITHUB_PAT and maybe mention you understand Vienna has it ...   But I would not expect any short-term fixes, sadly.

Comment: For the record, my package submission failed pre-tests because of this NOTE but reverse dependency checks were triggered anyways before I could explain why the NOTE should be ignored and the package update was subsequently released on CRAN. Also, I suggested to use GITHUB_PATH.

Comment: It is called `GITHUB_PAT` for _personal access token_ (IIRC).  No H.  And yes, Uwe's scripts don't halt over the NOTE so that is normal too.  So congrats on a new CRAN upload, and everybody is happy.